# SQL Server installation errors

Tags: sql-server-2008

I've been trying to install SQL Server 2008 R2 with tools.

I've downloaded [thisn version](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=23650&hash=DSRuedesAXmoylSKLm7lVoq2c2AdQJ9NXTiRzxIHP3wegrPa9nJjvInskz%2brHMoSg7TLEdnhqi6%2bjy3ibO9F9g==) and it just won't work!

I've had some problems installing Visual Studio SP1 due to silverlight4 being already installed, so I figured i needed to uninstall everything that had something to do with sql server, so I did.

Still the errors show up.

These 2 errors show up at the beginning of the installation during "Setup support files".

(I can't post more than 2 url's yet, so Ive put all the screenshots in 1 image, sorry)

[Here](http://begijnhof.no-ip.org:8080/Brol/s1.png)

The first error is the top left one, and retry fails, and when I hit cancel a few secs later the second error pops up and the installation terminates.

My OS is W7 x64 with all updates installed.

I don't really know how to go on actually. I've searched for hours yesterday without any results.

Anybody got a clue? Before I reinstall every .net-related programs.

Thanks in advance!

Edit:
So far I've tried:

- I checked if the first file shown in error 1 is actually there, and it is.
- Tried to run the setup explicitly as administrator
- I checked if the second file/folder was present, and it was not. So I manually created the folder and file, which then causes the
  first error to say the same, but then it says can't create
  \SqlSupport_Cpu64_1_ComponentUpdate_1.log, then I tried
  to create an empty file with that name and extention. This makes the installer
  append the filename with "_1". If I create that file too, it just
  appends with a higher count.
- Uninstalled every sql server related program (e.g sql server compact)
- Reset all the permissions on the e: disk and formatted it.

Comment: This question will be better answered here: http://dba.stackexchange.com/?as=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the cause of the problem. Recently I'd set my default program files folder to my hdd, because my C: is a 60 GB SSD. The key is located in the register at HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion. The keys "ProgramFilesDir" and "ProgramFilesDir (x86)" are the ones that need to be default ("C:\Program Files" and "C:\Program Files (x86)") in order for it to work.